# How to highlight table row on hover using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to highlight table row on hover (something like [this](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tablecloth/)) using CSS only (without JavaScript)?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, a row is possible but not a column.

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

works with most browsers

```
table tr:hover td {
  background: #efefef;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer as it will not highlight the table header!

Comment: Great answer . tnx

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible but you have to worry about browser compatibility here is an example

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tbl {width: 640px;}
    .tbl tr {background-color: Blue; height: 24px}
    .tbl tr:hover {background-color: Red;}
</style>


<table class="tbl">
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case you would add it to a table row using a stylesheet rule as in this CSS code example below:

```
    tr:hover {
      background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

Full Example:

```css
    .hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .hoverTable td{ 
        padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    .hoverTable tr{
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Text 1A</td><td>Text 1B</td><td>Text 1C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 2A</td><td>Text 2B</td><td>Text 2C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 3A</td><td>Text 3B</td><td>Text 3C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Source](https://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/highlight-table-row.php)

Comment: This answer is taken verbatim from [here](https://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/highlight-table-row.php) - don't forget to credit your source or people may think you're passing off the answer as your own.

Comment: You are right, I will add the source.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about Internet Explorer, the [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_hover.asp) CSS pseudo-class works with any element.

If you *do* care about IE, you can find a workaround [here](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Comment: IE7 and newer support :hover

Comment: Nobody cares about IE6 anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
   tr.tr-hover-class:hover {
      background: grey !important;
   }
</style>

<table>
   <tr class='tr-hover-class'></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How does this functionally differs from accepted answer?

Comment: implemented via additional class, not overriding standard <tr>

Comment: Accepted answer's idea is to use `:hover` pseudo-class along with setting `background-color` and your answer does not differs from it.

Comment: in my variant 'hover' effect will be applied only for <tr> with specific class ('tr-hover-class')